# Reverse LinkedList in one line

Tags: go, linked-list

I just found a solution for Reverse LinkedList on LeetCode using one line in Go. It realy works, but I can't understand how.

There it is:

```golang
func reverseList(head *ListNode) (prev *ListNode) {
    for head != nil {
        prev, head, head.Next = head, head.Next, prev 
    }
    
    return
}
```

For example let the list is `[1->2->3->4->5->nil]`.

I got that it's work like:

1. Firstly go execute `head.Next = prev` (`head.Next = nil`, so now `head = [1->nil]`)
2. Then, `prev = head` (At this step `prev = [1->nil]` like `head` in previous step)
3. `head = head.Next` and there is magic. For `prev` on second step Go was use `head = [1->nil]`, but after this step `head = [2->3->4->5->nil]`

So while `head != nil` it's iterates and at 2nd step `prev = [2->1->nil]` , `head = [3->4->5->nil]` and so on.

This line can be represented like:

```golang
for head != nil {
        a := *head
        prev, a.Next = &a, prev
        head = head.Next
    }
```

Am I right? Why does it work like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Variables on the left side of the expression, are assigned to the values on the right side of the expression at that time. This is a clever use of the language.

To make it easier to understand let's go through an example.

### Setup

This is our linked list: 
1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> nil

Before the function is executed,

- head is *Node 1
- prev is nil (uninitialized)
- head.Next is *Node 2

### Step by step

```
prev, head, head.Next = head, head.Next, prev
```

Let's break this down,

- prev (nil) = head (*Node 1)
- head (*Node 1) = head.Next (*Node 2)
- head.Next (*Node 2) = prev (nil)

The next iteration,

- prev (*Node 1) = head (*Node 2)
- head (*Node 2) = head.Next (*Node 3)
- head.Next (*Node 3) = prev (*Node 1)

### Summary

Basically, it reverses `head.Next` to the previous node and moves prev and head to the next nodes.

Compare this to the textbook algorithm in Go to make it clear:

```
func reverseList(head *ListNode) *ListNode {
    var prev *ListNode

    for head != nil {
        nextTemp := head.Next
        head.Next = prev
        prev = head
        head = nextTemp
    }

    return prev
}
```

Comment: "assignment happens without sequence" is questionable. The sequence of operations is specified in the [language spec](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Assignment_statements) "The assignment proceeds in two phases. First, the operands of index expressions and pointer indirections (including implicit pointer indirections in selectors) on the left and the expressions on the right are all evaluated in the usual order. Second, the assignments are carried out in left-to-right order.".

Comment: @Brits This is actually what I needed. Now I get it, thank you!

Comment: @Brits Sorry, I have caused a misunderstanding here. What I meant is that variables aren't assigned in different expressions. You're totally right. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @agcgn no worries - thanks for trying to answer, and feel free to incorporate the feedback in your answer (then George228 may accept it).